# C# .net The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Int64' type is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

C# / .Net 4.6.1 / Visual Studio 2017

I am having issues with an MS SQL query.  The query joins in several tables across two databases (on the same server).  The result goes into a list of "object".  The exception I get is:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' 
>       type to the 'System.Int64' type is not valid.

I have seen other SO questions on this and similar errors but I am not seeing the problem here.  `personId` is a long.  All of the various `...Id` fields are `bigint` in the DB and `long` in the model.

The query is:

```
try {
    var personId = GetPersonId(netid);

    var personIdParam = new SqlParameter {
        Value = personId,
        DbType = DbType.Int64,
        ParameterName = "PERSONID"
    };

    using (var pdb = new PersonnelContext()) {
        var foo = pdb.Database.SqlQuery<PersonToSpaceInfo>(@"
        SELECT
               'Member',
               sGroup.GroupId,
               sGroup.PersonnelGroupId,
               sGroup.Name,
               Space.SpaceId,
               Space.RoomId,
               SiteSpaceUse.TypeDescription
        FROM
             Personnel.Personnel.Memberships AS Memberships
             INNER JOIN Space.dbo.Person AS Person
                 ON Memberships.PersonId = Person.PersonnelPersonId
                    AND Person.PersonnelPersonId = @PERSONID
             INNER JOIN Space.dbo.[Group] AS sGroup
                 ON Memberships.GroupId = sGroup.PersonnelGroupId
             INNER JOIN Space.dbo.GroupList AS GroupList
                 ON sGroup.GroupId = GroupList.GroupId
             INNER JOIN Space.dbo.Space AS Space
                 ON GroupList.SpaceId = Space.SpaceId
                    AND Space.IsActive = 1
             INNER JOIN Space.dbo.SiteSpaceUse AS SiteSpaceUse
                 ON Space.SpaceId = SiteSpaceUse.SpaceId
        WHERE  GETDATE() BETWEEN Memberships.StartDate 
                         AND ISNULL(Memberships.EndDate, GETDATE())
        ",
            personIdParam).ToList();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("get group list failed: " + e.Message);
}
```

The result object is:

```
public class PersonToSpaceInfo {
    public string PersonType { get; set; }
    public long GroupId { get; set; }
    public long PersonnelGroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public long SpaceId { get; set; }
    public string RoomId { get; set; }
    public string TypeDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) 
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.GetUserActiveGroups(String user) in C:\Users\me\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 560
```

**Edit**

Line 560 in the stacktrace is the `var foo = pdb.Database...` line above.  `GetPersonId()` returns `long`.

The models were created using the code-first interface.  The following are model snippets requested by @mjwills

GroupList.GroupId / 
GroupList.SpaceId

```
public partial class GroupList {
    public long GroupId { get; set; }
    public long SpaceId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Memberships.GroupId / 
Memberships.PersonId

```
public partial class Membership {
    public long PersonId { get; set; }
    public long GroupId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Person.PersonnelPersonId

```
public partial class Person {
    public long PersonId { get; set; }
    public long PersonnelPersonId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

SiteSpaceUse.SpaceId

```
public partial class SiteSpaceUse {
    public long SpaceId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Space.SpaceId

```
public partial class Space 
    public long SpaceId { get; set; }
    public long BuildingId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

sGroup.GroupId / 
sGroup.PersonnelGroupId

```
public partial class Group {
    public long GroupId { get; set; }
    public long PersonnelGroupId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Edit 2**
Just tried replacing the `SqlParameter` in the query with a valid three digit number and i still get the error.  The query works in SQL Server Management Studio.  I'll delete the model and connection string info and recreate to see what happens.

What happens is noting changes...

Comment: What line does this occur on? What does `var personId = GetPersonId(netid);` actually return (int32 or int64)?

Comment: Line 560 in the stacktrace is the `var foo =  pdb.Database.SqlQuery<PersonToSpaceInfo>(...)` line above. `GetPersonId` returnd `long`.

Comment: Can you assure us that personId is a long by declaring it as such?

Comment: Yes.  Changing `var personId = GetPersonId(netid);` to `long personId ; personId = GetPersonId(netid);` both compiles and runs and the same exception is thrown on the same place.

Comment: Had to ask as you wrote that all ...Id fields are bigInt, but RoomId is declared as a string.  Not the source of the error your getting, but wanted to make sure it really is a long.

Comment: Can you post the EF model XML?

Comment: Also - not related to the problem here, but note that your `WHERE` clause should be rearranged to be [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/634824).  Always put fields on the left-side of the operator and arguments on the right.  (You'll have to break up the `BETWEEN` into separate statements.)

Comment: For the question at hand, are you *sure* those three `long` fields in are actually `bigint` in the database?

Comment: Yeah, `RoomId` is a string.  We have places like: B1203C and other goodness

Comment: Yup, every single db table has `bigint` in those places.

Comment: @ClayVerValen: which model file(s) in particular are you requesting?  I will be away from a keyboard for several hours or overnight.  Could be tomorrow morning before I can respond.

Comment: Really need to see the model XML as EF does not validate the SSDL against the DB.  Materialization errors can be caused by a mismatch here.

Comment: Should look something like:
`<EntityType Name="ORDERS">  
          <Key> 
            <PropertyRef Name="OR_NUMBER" /> 
          </Key> 
          <Property Name="OR_CUSTOMER" Type="int" /> 
          <Property Name="OR_EDATE" Type="date" /> 
          <Property Name="OR_INVOICE" Type="int" /> 
          <Property Name="OR_QTY" Type="int" /> 
          <Property Name="OR_SDATE" Type="date" /> 
          <Property Name="OR_TERMS" Type="varchar" MaxLength="2" /> 
          <Property Name="OR_VENDOR" Type="int" /> 
        </EntityType>`

Comment: @ClayVerValen: I do not see an XML file associated with my models.  These are code-first if that makes a difference.  If the file you are interested in has a specific name or should live in a particular place please let me know.  I have used winGrep to search for `<EntityType...` in the whole project and can't find a match.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.  It turns out that one of the DB context connections was pointing at the production DB server.  The error message generated was not helpful.